# Application Insights beta-7 does not work

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I am trying to use Application Insights in Azure. And I do everything like in examples. However when I try to call

```
app.UseApplicationInsightsRequestTelemetry()
```

in Configuration my web app stop working. I try to create TelemetryClient manually using the constructor but

```
_telemetryClient.TrackException(ex);
```

do nothing.

It seems to me that something wrong with injections. I amusing Autofac and try to inject it

```
_telemetryClient = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<TelemetryClient>();
```

but it does not help as well.

Are there ideas what is wrong?

Comment: are there any exceptions?  you need to clarify what "my web app stop working" means.  there could be lots of things that are wrong, so we need more info to narrow it down for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct answer is that we need to get correct TelemetryClient object. Don't know why is it no documentation about this, but it should looks like:

```
app.UseExceptionHandler(errorApp =>
{
var telemetry = ServiceProviderExtensions.GetService<TelemetryClient>(errorApp.ApplicationServices);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you called `services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);` as mentioned [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnet5/wiki/Getting-Started)

Also please +1 this [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnet5/issues/78)